# Visual Studio Transact-SQL Editor changes SQL Query too much

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and when I execute an SQL query VS changes it, for example substitutes name of database for tables.

If I type:

```
SELECT id FROM table
```

Then VS changes that to

```
SELECT MYBASE.TABLE.ID FROM MYBASE.TABLE
```

How to turn off this feature? Can't find in the Options :(

Comment: Why do you want to turn it off? It looks like it is trying to fully qualify the SQL object; this is a good thing.

Comment: I use a Transbase, and after this change got syntax error when query not simple.